# why is counter greater then end - FOR statement VB

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

When program finished FOR statment, counter is greater then end number. As long i know, at the end(after next) counter has same value then end value (for counter=1 to end). Can someone please explain.

```
Dim all_lines = 5
Dim line As Integer

Label1.Text = ""
For line = 1 To all_lines
     Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
Next

Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
```

Result:

```
1/5
2/5
3/5
4/5
5/5
6/5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop counter is basically incremented at the `Next` statement and then tested against the limits at the `For` statement.  If it's not greater than the upper limit then the loop is entered, otherwise it exits.  It happens this way because you can specify a `Step` of greater than 1 and the loop doesn't want to calculate ahead of time whether the current loop counter value plus the `Step` value will exceed the upper limit.  It just waits until the loop counter actually contains that value and tests it then.

It's important to realise that the `For` loop is really just syntactic sugar and the compiled code is basically a `Do` loop.  If you wrote your code as a `Do` loop then it would be more obvious why your loop counter exceeds the upper limit:

```
Dim all_lines = 5
Dim line As Integer

Label1.Text = ""
line = 1

Do While line <= all_lines
    Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
    line += 1
Loop

Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
```

You really shouldn't be using the loop counter outside the loop in the vast majority of cases anyway.  That means that you shouldn't be declaring it outside the loop, i.e. do this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To upperBound
```

rather than this:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To upperBound
```

In any case where you actually need to use the loop counter outside the loop, it would be because the loop is doing a search and you should therefore have an `Exit For` statement inside your loop that will prevent the loop counter being incremented further.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, for explaination. Is this new in .NET? I was using from TurboBasic to vb6 and didn't notice that.

Comment: I've never used VB6 so I don't know how it worked but VB.NET has worked this way since .NET 1.0 as far as I'm aware. That said, the ability to declare the loop counter variable with the For statement was only added in VB.NET 2003, which came with .NET 1.1

Comment: Thanks again. It's very helpfull to know that

Comment: The externally defined counter being persistent has been true since "Adam was a lad" in most languages. (I know, cos I went to school with him LOL). As @jmcilhinney says, it's best NOT to use variables defined outside the loop unless there is some pressing reason to do so. This is ESPECTIALLY true of the For Each construct using classes, since whatever class you are using can stay alive for a lot longer than you expect it to.

Comment: VB6 would perform in the same manner, with the same code.  After exiting the loop when the upper bound had been reached, the loop counter/index will be greater than the upper bound (specifically, it will be _step_ greater, with _step_ defaulting to 1).

Answer (score 0):

It's the very last line outside the loop:

```
Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
```

Remove this.

Code should be:

```
Dim all_lines = 5
Dim line As Integer

Label1.Text = ""
For line = 1 To all_lines
     Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)
Next
```

Having the extra line is causing your issue.  "Line" will equal 6 in order to get exit out of the loop, and you're doing an operation on it - outside the loop:

Label1.Text += line & "/" & all_lines & Chr(13)

so yes, you will get the results you're experiencing.  Just remove the last line of code.

Comment: But after NEXT, I need "line" value... extra line is just for seeing issue

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of the question.  I don't think the OP was asking how to get the right output but rather they arte wanting to know how the loop counter can ever be greater than the loop's upper limit.

Comment: @MirkoTipka, no you do NOT need `line`.  Based on the code you have, you are expecting `line` to have the same value as `all_lines` so why would you not just use `all_lines` after the loop?

Comment: "line" would of been incremented though as part of the For Loop counter.  "line" would have to be <expected value +1> at the very end in order to get out of the loop, otherwise you'd be stuck in an infinite loop forever more...